# Can we use share point directory as destination to my file sink?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

We have a spring cloud data flow stream which reads an excel from an SFTP source location and processes it and generates an output excel which is to be copied to a common share point folder.

Is there any way we can do this...?

We could write to sftp sink, but our requirement is to create the output in share point folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [Microsoft SharePoint](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/sharepoint/collaboration) Sink implementation. You have to use some other intermediary to store the file then transfer it with some other Microsoft tool or implement such a SharePoint Sink yourself: https://medium.com/xebia-engineering/java-use-microsoft-graph-api-to-access-sharepoint-sites-1a26427c9b83

> What SharePoint is:

> SharePoint is a customizable web application that can integrate with other Microsoft services and applications, such as Outlook, Teams, Microsoft Viva, OneDrive for Business, and more.

So, as long as I know OneDrive, there will be just enough for you to use File Sink to store the file. Then OneDrive will sync it with your cloud account and from there you need to configure your SharePoint to sync with your OneDrive.

Comment: Thank you Artem Bilan. Is there any way to get notified or call another service once file is written to an intermediate location, Instead of creating another stream listening to the output location of the first stream.

Comment: I think this deserves its own SO question according to rules over here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask